# unable to sign In for MultiTenant Azure AD using Custom policies in AAD B2C from my asp.net core web app

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have set up multitenant sign in sign up in Azure AD using a B2C custom Policy.

After uploading the policy and testing using <kbd>Run Now</kbd> button in Azure portal with a reply url `https://jwt.ms` and everything worked as expected, I got the token and my user name etc.

When I try to sign in with my web app sign in, a dialogue box appeared, when i choose to sign in with social accounts and I pick my *AAD Tenant* it does not work and results in an error with endpoint:

```
https://localhost:{myport}/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/Error
```

with no specific error code.

I am interested in help on how to debug and resolve this.

Comment: You should not completely modify the original question into a new question, so that it seems that my answer is meaningless. If you have a new question or follow-up question, you should edit the original post and place an UPDATE, or open a new post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Azure B2C standard customer policy starterpack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack).

Follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) to configure the multi-tenant sign-in.

The most important thing is configuring **ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes** in the `TechnicalProfile`.

The format is:

```
<Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id of tenant A},https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id of tenant B}</Item>
```